# customizing devise flash message after sign up

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to show appropriate flash message to the user after he signs up.
My app is configured so that user is logged in automatically after the registration, but he has to confirm the email (he can be logged in for 5 days without confirming the email).

With my current configuration, devise will display the following flash message to the user:

```
Welcome! You have signed up successfully.
```

I would like to tell them that they have to confirm the email:

```
Welcome.. You have signed up successfully. Please confirm your email address by clicking the link..
```

As I see, this message is already defined in the locales/devise.en.yml with the signed_up_but_unconfirmed but why its not showing up with my configuration?

How should I fix this?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled devise's `confirmable` module in your user model, after registration the user should be seeing the default text:

"A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your account."

The message above  as defined in the `devise.en.yml` file with the key `en:devise:registrations:signed_up_but_unconfirmed`

Comment: I have enabled confirmable, but after I installed the devise (which was originally without confirmable). However, I get a different message although confirmable is enabled. Any idea?